# Rails BLOB/TEXT column used in key specification without a key length

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I am trying to run a rails migration and I am seeing the error "BLOB/TEXT column used in key specification without a key length"...  However, I'm specifying the length in the migration class.  Rails seems to ignore this when generating the SQL statement from the migration.  Any clues?

Here's my migration class:

```
class AddIndexToAccounts < ActiveRecord::Migration
def self.up
  add_index :TACCOUNT, :NAMEX, :length => 5
end
def self.down
  remove_index :TACCOUNT, :NAMEX
end
end
```

And here's the error output.  It seems to have seen the length specification, but it's not present in the SQL statement that it generates:

```
** [out :: 192.168.10.7] -- add_index(:TACCOUNT, :NAMEX, {:length=>5})
** [out :: 192.168.10.7] rake aborted!
** [out :: 192.168.10.7] An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:
** [out :: 192.168.10.7] 
** [out :: 192.168.10.7] Mysql::Error: BLOB/TEXT column 'NAMEX' used in key specification without a key length: CREATE  INDEX `index_TACCOUNT_on_NAMEX` ON `TACCOUNT` (`NAMEX`)
```

Comment: Indexing `TEXT` columns is usually a bad idea. Why is this column of that type in the first place if you need it indexed?

Comment: I agree with you, that's why i'm only trying to index the first few characters.  I'm just working with the database structure i was given

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try being more specific to see if that tricks it into working:

```
add_index :TACCOUNT, :NAMEX, :length => { :NAMEX => 5 }
```

As a last resort you can crete the index the "hard way" using SQL directly by adjusting the incorrect `ADD INDEX` statement and using `execute` on the correct one.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I didn't realize you could execute raw SQL in a migration...  Now to try and figure out why we're using a longtext field here....  Thanks again!

Comment: You can do whatever you want in a migration. The helper methods like `add_index` are only there for your convenience. You should be careful when doing things like this as there's a chance your test database might not have the correct indexes applied if the schema dumper can't make sense of your structure. This sometimes makes tests run very slowly if you load in a lot of data without indexes you expected to be there.